# Java : passing argument for Run Length Encoding

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

I want to test the Run Length Encoding algorithm that I have on a windows executable file (.exe), but I am not receiving output when I run the program. There are no compilations errors; the run only states that the Build is successful, and nothing else.

Here is the code:

```
package runlength;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.BinaryStdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.BinaryStdOut;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class RunLength {
    private static final int R   = 256;
    private static final int lgR = 8;

    public static void expand() { 
        boolean b = false; 
        while (!BinaryStdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int run = BinaryStdIn.readInt(lgR);
            for (int i = 0; i < run; i++)
                BinaryStdOut.write(b);
            b = !b;
        }
        BinaryStdOut.close();
    }

    public static void compress() { 
        char run = 0; 
        boolean old = false;
        while (!BinaryStdIn.isEmpty()) { 
            boolean b = BinaryStdIn.readBoolean();
            if (b != old) {
                BinaryStdOut.write(run, lgR);
                run = 1;
                old = !old;
            }
            else { 
                if (run == R-1) { 
                    BinaryStdOut.write(run, lgR);
                    run = 0;
                    BinaryStdOut.write(run, lgR);
                }
                run++;
            } 
        } 
        BinaryStdOut.write(run, lgR);
        BinaryStdOut.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Downloads\\adobe shockwave player setup.exe")); 


        if (args.length > 0)
        {
        switch (args[0]) {
            case "-":
                compress();
                break;
            case "+":
                expand();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal command line argument");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am not convinced that I am properly passing the .exe file in my main function, but I am not sure if that is the problem. Thank you to all who would like to help me understand this problem.

Comment: I don't see how running this Java program would say "Build successful". And I don't see what windows exe files have to do with runing a Java program. What are you doing exactly? Why is your main method opening a Reader (whose role is to read characters) over a binary executable file, and doing nothing with it?

Comment: Don't understand what's your problem but to launch an executable, you can use [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))

Comment: If I understand correctly, he's not trying to run the exe, but see if he is able to compress and expand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/debuggingtips_Java.html

It sounds like you are trying to run the program with the Java compiler (javac). Once the class files are built, you should be able to run (from the directory containing the runlength directory) `java runlength.RunLength -`. What is the output of that?

Also, what tool are you using to build? If it's just javac it won't say "build successful", it just won't produce output (unless something went wrong).